# Output parameter used to insert a row in same table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Thanks for your help Guys

I am working on a Asp.net based project and my requiremnent is to generate a PARTNO with the combination of MaterialType+ProductID and - 4digit random number

NOTE: ProductID is Primary key and also set it to output parameter

for example If material type is 500 and product ID generated 55 and random no generated 5434, then part no become 555-5434

Now my question is how could I store partno in same table, I am somewhat trying like that

```
        Connection.Open()
        Dim trn As SqlClient.SqlTransaction
        trn = Connection.BeginTransaction
        Using trn


            Dim sqlcode As New SqlParameter("@ProductID", Products.ProductID)
            sqlcode.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput                 
            Using Command As New SqlCommand("Product_Write", Connection, trn)

                Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                Command.Parameters.Add(sqlcode)                     Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaterialType", Materialtype.MaterialTypeCode)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", category.CategoryId)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", Products.ProductName)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDescription", Products.ProductDescription)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductActive", Products.ProductActive)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImage", Products.ProductImage)
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNo", 0)


                Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Products.ProductID = CInt(sqlcode.Value)
                'Insert the part no 

                Dim random As New Random()
                Dim value As Integer = random.Next(9999)
                Dim PartNo As String = CType((Materialtype.MaterialTypeCode + Products.ProductID).ToString + "-" + value.ToString, String)


                'Dont know what to do 

                trn.Commit()

                Connection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return Products
End Function




ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_Write]
@ProductID bigint OUTPUT,
@MaterialType int,
@CategoryID bigint,
@ProductName VARCHAR(MAX),
@ProductDescription VARCHAR(MAX),
@ProductActive Bit,
@ProductImage VARCHAR(MAX),
@PartNo VARCHAR(30)
AS
IF (@ProductID=0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO T_Product(
MaterialType,
CategoryID,
ProductName,
ProductDescription,
ProductActive,
ProductImage,
PartNo)
VALUES(
@MaterialType,
@CategoryID,
@ProductName,
@ProductDescription,
@ProductActive,
@ProductImage,
@PartNo)

SET @ProductID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END 
ELSE
 UPDATE T_Product SET
      MaterialType=@MaterialType,
      CategoryID=@CategoryID,
      ProductName=@ProductName,
      ProductDescription=@ProductDescription,
      ProductActive=@ProductActive,
      ProductImage=@ProductImage,
      PartNo=@PartNo
WHERE ProductID=@ProductID
                Please help me out
```

Thanks

Comment: you could do the work in the stored procedure using the inserted table functionality or even scope_identity.

Comment: Can you please me a example if it is possible for you

Comment: You need to create a new update query or a stored procedure to update the value of PARTNO like Update Table Set PartNo=NewPartNo where ProductID=@ProductId and then again call ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Could you post the code for the 'Product_Write' stored procedure? It would liekly be easiest to set the part no there...

Comment: Just added the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you can update the Stored Procedure you would need something along these lines

```
declare @id int
set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
UPDATE <Table> Set PartNo = MaterialType + convert(varchar(max),@id) + convert(varchar(4),CEILING(9999*RAND())) Where ID = @id
```

Comment: Well, I cant use this approach because client already got some partno's and I need to make sure that it is not duplicated

Comment: Sorry forgot to append in ID which would stop that.